# Read contents from Google docs using php

Tags: php, yii, google-docs-api

How to read the contents from google docs? is there any api available for php? am using `yii` framework..

Comment: U may look this http://kovshenin.com/2009/google-docs-api-client-login-with-php-and-curl/

Comment: @safarov thanks for the link..i got the auth string..but the rest is not working.

Comment: there is api for google spreadsheet, read the documentation and extend  this library or search for another php library

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453172/need-to-upload-files-to-google-docs-from-my-application-and-store-reference-to-t/2576573#2576573

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google provide an API which is accessible via PHP. You need to authenticate using your gmail username & password.

Look this :
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

[How to use the Google SpreadSheets API to feed data to an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314001/how-to-use-the-google-spreadsheets-api-to-feed-data-to-an-application)

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/php_client_lib.html

~K